# Performing INNER JOIN, GROUP BY, and COUNT on Django models

Tags: sql, database, django, models, inner-join

I am having problems understanding how to make complex queries (or even simple ones) using Django models. I am looking to do an inner join, group by, and count in one statement using django models.

Example:

```
Select ab.userid, count(ab.userid) as bids, u.username 
from auctionbids ab 
inner join users u on ab.userid=u.id 
group by ab.userid 
order by numbids desc;
```

This type of query is very common and straight forward so I have to imagine it can be done with django models but it is not apparent from the documentation.

edit: added models

```
class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Auctionbids(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you post your models.py file I can probably give you a more precise answer, but I think what you want is the [Django Aggregration API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses)

You would use it something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
User.objects.all().annotate(bids=Count('auctionbids')).order_by('bids')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I thought the SQL would be self explanatory so I didn't post the model.  I edited the original to include the model to be more explicit.  I'll give your solution a try.

Comment: So the query seems to work (I get back technically good data) however logically the data received is wrong.  With the SQL statement, it first selects the auctionbids then inner joins.  I seem that the django query is selecting all users, where many users do not have auctionbids.  As a really, the Users.objects.all() will pull all users which is a major hit on the DB.  I guessing I need to user a filter instead of all?

Comment: added the filter to objects to remove the full query of users.  final result: User.objects.filter(auctionbids__isnull=False).annotate(bids=Count('auctionbids')).order_by('-bids')